# List comprehension to find all multiples of each number in list less than a number

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write a function that will find all numbers that are a multiple of at least one number in a list where the multiple is less than a certain number. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
def MultiplesUnderX(MultArray,X):
    '''
    Finds all the multiples of each value in MultArray that
    are below X.
    MultArray: List of ints that multiples are needed of
    X: Int that multiples will go up to
    '''
    return [i if (i % x == 0 for x in MultArray) else 0 for i in range(X)]
```

For example, MultiplesUnderX([2,3],10) would return [2,3,4,6,8,9]. I'm a little unsure how to do this with the for loop inside of the list comprehension.

Comment: Why is `3` not in the result list?

Comment: Because I haven't slept in 15 hours.

Comment: `(i % x == 0 for x in MultArray)` is a generator expression, not a "for-loop inside of the list comprehension (such a thing is not possible, since a for-loop requires a for-statement). It returns a generator object, which is truthy. You want to consume that generator using `any`

Comment: You can also `[True for x in MultiArray if i % x == 0]` then you don't need the `any()`

Comment: @Wyrmwood `any()` with a generator expression is short circuiting though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Python any() function to check if there is at least one instance of a divider in MultArray:

```
def MultiplesUnderX(MultArray,X):

    return [i for i in range(X) if any(i % x == 0 for x in MultArray)]
```

Comment: An extra parenthesis in there, but I love it!

Comment: This returns a list with a lot of extra `0`s in it, due to the `else 0` in your comprehension. Also, in 2.7 the `xrange` will be a bit more efficient as to avoid the creation of a giant list up front.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python built-in function `any` which returns `True` if the iterable passed in contains any truth-y values in combination with a conditional at the end of the list comprehension limiting the list to only elements that satisfy the `any` call.

```
def get_multiples_under(factors, max):
    return [i for i in xrange(1, max) if any(i % factor == 0 for factor in factors)]
```

Your desired output is shown as such:

```
multiples = [2, 3]
print get_multiples_under(multiples, 10)
# [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version of this algorithm which may be more efficient if the list is mostly co-prime, you can just use `range(i, X, i)` to generate only the multiples of `i`, then use [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) to merge the iterators such that the iterator returned is sorted.

The last step is to eliminate duplicates as you go:

```
import heapq

def all_multiples(multi_list, max_N):
    gens = []
    for fac in sorted(set(multi_list)):
        # In Python 3 this is a generator of all multiples of "fac" less
        # than max_N. In Python 2 use xrange
        gens.append(range(fac, max_N, fac))

    # This will do a heap merge on the generators (which are already sorted)
    o = heapq.merge(*gens)
    last = None
    for val in o:
        if val != last:
            yield val
            last = val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi_list = [2, 4, 7]
    print(list(all_multiples(multi_list, 12)))
    # [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10]
```